# The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for FormsViewGroup.dll (v7.1) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v6.0) xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

the error is on visual studio 2017 and xamarin:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Warning       The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for FormsViewGroup.dll (v7.1) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v6.0).
>   You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
>
> IpiCommunicationXamarin.Android    D:\XmarainTest\IpiCommunicationXamarin\IpiCommunicationXamarin\IpiCommunicationXamarin.Android\IpiCommunicationXamarin.Android.csproj

Answer (score 24):

It means you have a reference (**FormsViewGroup.dll**) which uses the **Android Framework Version** of **7.1**, but your project only targets **6.0**.

You can update your **Android Target Framework  Version** by going to your `Android Project Properties` (right click the `Android Project` and click `Properties`) and go to `Application tab`. If you can't find the **7.1** on the dropdown, you can install it using **Android SDK Manager** (I think **7.1** is **API 25**).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Open the SDK Manager application and install the API 25. Then restart your Visual Studio and you will have the v7.1 or v7.0. Just install the latest (Nougat, I think)

Comment: What is I want to target 6.0. How to decrease $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for FormsViewGroup.dll?

Comment: My problem is that FormsViewGroup.dll is vv8.0 but the projects is v7.1. I'm a Xamarin newbie and just installed VS2017. Sounds to me that I've somehow got a later version control mixed in with my installed framework.

I was following the example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn879698.aspx

Will post back when I solve it.

Comment: Tried the post here but didn't solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994419/how-to-decrease-targetframeworkversion-for-formsviewgroup-dll-from-v7-1-to

Comment: @Nick can you please share if got around this issue? I am also facing same thing.

Answer (score 6):

I feel it's kinda late for this answer but just had the same problem and this is the first post I found so I'll answer here what worked for me.

Inside Visual just go to Tools>Android>Android SDK Manager...

There just choose the latest version (or the one you are asked to use) and that should fix it.

[image: Just in case here is the screenshot]

Comment: Did not work for me and I do not see why this should work.

Answer (score 1):

There is something more subtle happening here . The issue is Xamarin.Forms version of Visual Studio version you are using . For example I was using Visual Studio 2019 it has Xamarin.Forms 4.2 . It requires that I ***compile*** with ***Android 8.1 or above*** .  But I can deploy to Android version less than that by setting the minimum version of android and then deploying to it.

**Project Properties >> Android Manifest >> Minimum Android Version dropdown**

See here

[Xamarin choosing TargetFramework and MinimumAndroidVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49831554/8917467)

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me this way:
Inside Visual Studio go to Tools>Android>Android SDK Manager... and ununstalled the latest Platform, setting it to be highest the Android 6.0 - Marshmallow

[Android SDKs and Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSfCC.png)

Also at project properties set the Target Framework like below shown:

[Target Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w83cp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try use menu button **Build->Clean Solution**. It helped me.