# Xamarin choosing TargetFramework and MinimumAndroidVersion

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms application(currently only Android support). The default setup set TargetFramework to 7.1. The minimum android version for this project must be 7.0. This produces a warning:

> The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll (vv7.1) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
>   It seems natural to me, to compile for the version that you will be using. Is that not the case?

This articles *recommends* to always compile with the latest version. Is there any benefit to compiling with the latest version for my application?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=vswin#framework

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer is for Visual Studio 2017. If you are using Xamarin Studio for mac, then you have to look for similar option.

**The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll (vv7.1)**

It means, the project is using SDK 7.1 i.e. `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll (vv7.1)`.
May be you had selected `Compile Using Android Version (Target Framework)` lower than v7.1 in the project setting.

If you set `Android 7.1 Nougat` to compile your project it will work. 
You can set this from `Project Properties >> Application menu`

**The minimum android version for this project must be 7.0.**

This means the minimum Android OS version on which you want to make your App available.

This can be set from -

**Project Properties >> Android Manifest >> Minimum Android Version dropdown**

For more details - refer below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=vswin

Comment: I know how to change the Target Framework version, my question is should I? What are the advantages of compiling using a newer SDK, considering the app is not meant to run on a device with the same version?

Comment: You can use latest theme for example.

Comment: And this will work on an older version(assuming support libraries are installed) ?

Comment: Yes, it must.
In my project I had used Compile Using Android Version (Target Framework) = 7.1 
But target device OS is Android 4.4 and the app runs fine. I had not tested below that. There is a very nice explanation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=vswin

Comment: The explanation is very clear and provide idea about resolving any issue. Thanks